# sample different numbers of random rows

Tags: r, dataframe, random, dplyr

I want to sample 1:n rows from a data-frame randomly, 100 times (i.e. to give 2000 random data-frames).

I'm able to do this for say 10 random rows using the sample_n function:

```
ran_df <- sample_n(df, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

But how do I do this for all possible number of rows from my data-frame i.e. 1 row, 2 rows, 3 rows ... 20 rows?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
     bird_sp plant_sp value
1  species_a  plant_a     1
2  species_a  plant_a     1
3  species_a  plant_a     1
4  species_a  plant_a     1
5  species_a  plant_a     1
6  species_a  plant_b     1
7  species_a  plant_b     1
8  species_a  plant_b     1
9  species_a  plant_b     1
10 species_a  plant_c     1
11 species_a  plant_d     1
12 species_a  plant_d     1
13 species_b  plant_d     1
14 species_b  plant_d     1
15 species_b  plant_b     1
16 species_b  plant_b     1
17 species_b  plant_b     1
18 species_b  plant_b     1
19 species_b  plant_c     1
20 species_b  plant_c     1
```

Comment: I am getting a bit confused by the numbers. Does the dataframe only have 20 rows?

Comment: I'm confused too.. is this what you want? `lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sample_n(df, x, replace = T))`

Comment: Yes - so would generate 100 x 1 random rows, 100 x 2, 100 x 3 ... 100 x 20

Comment: Thanks! replicate(10, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sample_n(df, x, replace = T))  works. This gives me a list of dataframes. However, how would I then cast each of these dataframes in the list into matrices (i.e., plant_sp as rows and bird_sp as columns). I can do this with the original dataframe using: mat <- with(df, tapply(value, list(plant_sp, bird_sp),sum) and then convert NAs to 0's suing  mat[is.na(mat)]<-0

Answer (score 0):

User `sample_n` as @Mickey has suggested with `lapply` and then you can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` package or `do.call` from `base` package to join the list into a dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text = "bird_sp plant_sp value
                 1  species_a  plant_a     1
                 2  species_a  plant_a     1
                 3  species_a  plant_a     1
                 4  species_a  plant_a     1
                 5  species_a  plant_a     1
                 6  species_a  plant_b     1
                 7  species_a  plant_b     1
                 8  species_a  plant_b     1
                 9  species_a  plant_b     1
                 10 species_a  plant_c     1
                 11 species_a  plant_d     1
                 12 species_a  plant_d     1
                 13 species_b  plant_d     1
                 14 species_b  plant_d     1
                 15 species_b  plant_b     1
                 16 species_b  plant_b     1
                 17 species_b  plant_b     1
                 18 species_b  plant_b     1
                 19 species_b  plant_c     1
                 20 species_b  plant_c     1", header = TRUE)
# Use lapply 
samples_Data <- replicate(10, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sample_n(df, x, replace = T))) %>%
  bind_rows(.)
```